# Auto-connect Facebook user to my site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I have being searching for new stuff for my app when i accidentally ran into this site:
 http://docs.com/
While entering the site I was connected to my Facebook account and suddenly I saw my name/picture/id presented on that site, let me notice that **I didn't register to this site** and didn't gave it my access token..

Does somebody have an explanation to this phenomena?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for common developers.. This is because docs.com are part of an FB alliance "instant personalization" see this http://www.facebook.com/instantpersonalization/

Answer (score 0):

This is called [*Instant Personalization*](http://www.facebook.com/instantpersonalization/):

> Just as your News Feed on Facebook is built uniquely for you, instant
>   personalization sites let you easily bring your friends and interests
>   with you.
>
> Partners adhere to Facebook's guidelines and may only use
>   your public information to serve you a personalized experience. Public
>   information includes your name, profile picture, gender, networks, and
>   other information shared with everyone.
>
> **When you first arrive on a
>   participating site, you will see a notification and a way to turn off
>   the customized experience in one click.** Your information can only be
>   used to present you with a more personalized experience and cannot be
>   transferred to advertisers or used for any other purposes.

This feature is *only* available for Facebook partners and you could control and turn it off from your [Privacy Settings](http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy).